# How to disable default PowerPoint event functionality of double click and right click?

Tags: c#, events, mouseevent, vsto, powerpoint

In my PowerPoint Add-in using VSTO, I am implementing an `Application-level Mouse Hook` to capture mouse events like double click, right click, mouse over etc, by using `MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor.dll` downloaded from [Codeplex](https://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/). The reason I am doing this is because PowerPoint doesn't have mouse related events to listen to and the ones it gives are not fired in edit-mode of the PowerPoint.

In my Add-in when user clicks a chart a menu appears which allows the user to perform various functions on the chart. All is working fine. I have captured mouse events and a customized menu is shown but the problem arises when the menu is closed after performing some action the default menu of PowerPoint appears on the screen.

Example: When user double clicks on the chart, I show my form menu like this.

```
//Listening to the MouseDoubleClick event
MyMouseHookListener.MouseDoubleClick += MyMouseHookListener_MouseDoubleClick;

//MouseDoubleClickEvent
void MyMouseHookListener_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    FormMenu.ShowDialog(); //Displaying menu
}
```

This works fine, but when the user closes the form the default double click menu of PowerPoint Charts appears. Same is the problem with other mouse events.

How can I disable PowerPoint's event menus?

**Update:**

There is a `bool` property named `Cancel` which is provided by PowerPoint's `WindowBeforeDoubleClick` and `WindowBeforeRightClick` events. Which if set to `true` cancels the default action that PowerPoint performs when an event is fired. How can i access this property in my `MouseHook` events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several available events raised by the `MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor`. For a mouse down event you can choose to listen to either `MouseDown` or `MouseDownExt`. The latter supplies you with some extra options in the `MouseEventExtArgs` parameter, such as a `Handled` property. If you set this to true, the event will not propagate further.

When it comes to `MouseDoubleClick` event, there is no extended event available. I would therefore suggest that you implement the double click listener yourself by utilizing the `MouseDownExt` listener and counting the number of clicks that has occurred.

```
public void Initialize() {
    // Initialize your listener and set up event listeners
    MyMouseHookListener = new MouseHookListener(new AppHooker()) {Enabled = true};
    MyMouseHookListener.MouseDownExt += MyMouseHookListenerOnMouseDownExt;

    // UNDONE Delete when testing is done; included to show that the listener is never called
    MyMouseHookListener.MouseDoubleClick += MyMouseHookListenerOnMouseDoubleClick;
}

private static void MyMouseHookListenerOnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
{
    // NOTE: This listener should never be called
    Debug.Print("Mouse double-click!");
}

private static void MyMouseHookListenerOnMouseDownExt(object sender, MouseEventExtArgs mouseEventExtArgs)
{
    Debug.Print("Mouse down. Number of clicks: {0}", mouseEventExtArgs.Clicks);

    if (mouseEventExtArgs.Clicks == 2)
    {
        // TODO Insert your double-click code here
        mouseEventExtArgs.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

To be exhaustive, you should perhaps also test whether it is the left or right button that has been clicked, which you can to by checking the `MouseEventExtArgs.Button` property. A right-double-click will now be counted as a double-click, however, this is as far as I know similar to the original `MouseDoubleClick` event.